# How do I change my button image with navigation drawer opening and closing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, android-navigation

I have a navigation button for my navigation fragment which turns active and opens a navigation drawer menu upon click:
[image]

Now when I click it, it turns active as follows:
[image]

However, I want to associate it with a navigation drawer such a way that, even if I do not click the button and slide open the navigation drawer, the button turns active when the navigation drawer menu is open and when closed by sliding back in from right to left, the button turns red/inactive. The code which I am trying to work with is as follows:

```
private boolean mIsNavigationOpen = false;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationPanelFragment dlDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
public boolean isNavigationOpen() {

        return mIsNavigationOpen;

    }
//----------Code for Navigation open logo button active/inactive instances
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setNavigationOpen(final boolean isNavigationOpen) {
        this.mIsNavigationOpen = isNavigationOpen;
        final ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        if(isNavigationOpen) {
            mainButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_helios_active);
        } else {
            mainButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        }
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        //----------Code for Navigation Drawer setup
        // 2. App Icon 
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
                 actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                            R.drawable.arrow_up, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

                        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
                        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                           // getActionBar().setTitle(NavigationPanelFragment.activeFragmentTitle);
                           // invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                        }

                        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
                        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                         //   getActionBar().setTitle(NavigationPanelFragment.activeFragmentTitle);
                          //  invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                        }
                    };


                // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
                drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
          }
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
         actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
private void setupOnClickListenerForMainButton() {
        final ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                toggleNavigationPanel();


            }
        });
    }
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(final int featureId, final MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                toggleNavigationPanel();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
public void onNewsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(NewsFragment.TAG_NEWS_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = NewsFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
        //For swipe action close drawer on button click
         drawerLayout.closeDrawer(R.id.drawer);
    }
public void onListsClicked(final View view) {
        if(mIsNavigationOpen) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }

        if (isFragmentVisible(ListsContainerFragment.TAG_LIST_CONTAINER_FRAGMENT)) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mActiveFragment = ListsContainerFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
        updateActionBarTitle();
        //For swipe action close drawer on button click
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(R.id.drawer);
    }
private void toggleNavigationPanel() {
        //final FragmentStackManager manager = FragmentStackManager.getInstance();
        if (mIsNavigationOpen) {
            //NavigationPanelFragment.removeInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
            updateActionBarTitle();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(R.id.drawer);
        } else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(R.id.drawer);
            final TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title);
            title.setText(getString(R.string.title_applications));
            //NavigationPanelFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager(), manager.getTopTitle());
        }


        setNavigationOpen(!mIsNavigationOpen);
    }
```

You might want to concentrate on the main_button and togglenavigationpanel. I added the condition if(drawerlayout.isdraweropen(R.id.drawer)){closedrawerlayout...}
but it didn't do the trick. I was wondering if anyone has any idea regarding the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make use of `onDrawerClosed` and `onDrawerOpened`?

Comment: How do I use it ? Can you illustrate with code?

Comment: Also fyi I added public void onDrawerClosed(View view) { toggleNavigationPanel()}public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {toggleNavigationPanel()} it worked for the swipes but onclick it crashed with a null pointer exeption

Answer (score 0):

When you've set up the drawer a listener has been added which has callbacks for when the drawer is in either final state, so what you need to do is reset the drawable inside these callbacks. I've shown what I think your final code should look like, minus some cleaning up you need to do, hope it helps

```
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationPanelFragment dlDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private ImageButton mDrawerButton; //Store it! - findViewById is *Expensive*
private TextView mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title);
    mDrawerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.arrow_up, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            mDrawerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_helios_inactive);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            mDrawerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_helios_active);
        }

    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    setupOnClickListenerForMainButton(;
}

@Override //Note: I'd imagine this should be in onResume ...
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private void setupOnClickListenerForMainButton() {
    mDrawerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            toggleNavigationPanel();
        }
    });
}

...

private void toggleNavigationPanel() {
    //if ( drawerLayout.isOpen() ) { //I dont know what methods these objects have
    if ( dlDrawer.isOpen() ) { //but one of these must be sensibly storing its own state
        updateActionBarTitle();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(R.id.drawer);
    } else {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(R.id.drawer);
        mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.title_applications));
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be crashing at             mDrawerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_helios_active);
 with a null pointer exception. However, when I go back to my original implementation and just add toggleNavigationPanel() in Oncreate's onDrawerOpened/Ondrawerclosed, it does recognize the swipe for the nav drawer and switches the helios button to selected and deselected accordingly, but as soon as I click the helios button , it crashes with a null pointer exception, I wonder what is causing the crash

Comment: if you have toggleNavigationPanel()  inside the callback that's triggered by toggleNavigationPanel()'s action how will it ever work?

Make sure the image view is being found in oncreate (mDrawerButton) and look at your logcat for more information

Comment: I need to keep the isNavigationOpen() function too for the onclick of the button, so do I define the condition as if ( isNavigationOpen() || drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(R.id.drawer) ) { updateActionBarTitle();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(R.id.drawer);
    } else {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(R.id.drawer);
        mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.title_applications));} ?

Comment: Keeping that variable is asking for trouble as the drawer should know its state and then you are storing a separate representation of sate as well which can get out of sync. Use (or add if necessary) state to the drawer and an isDrawerOpen method. drawerLayout.closeDrawer and openDrawer should update the state so there is absolutely no reason to store it here, out of context

Comment: even if I change everything and place anythin inside public void onDrawerClosed(View view)  it crashes with a null pointer exception  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.updateDrawerState(DrawerLayout.java:459)
 at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback.onViewDragStateChanged(DrawerLayout.java:1348)
 at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.setDragState(ViewDragHelper.java:866)
 at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper$2.run(ViewDragHelper.java:335)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)