# Android Navigation Drawer custom Icons on drawer opened/closed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, android-navigation

I would like to customize my navigation drawer in the following manner:

instead of the current default animation that slides the menu icon slightly to the left i would like to have one icon displayed when the drawer is open and another when the drawer is closed.

Any ideas/leads onto where i could find anything like that?

I have done some research, was able to chance the action bar icon but that unfortunately this is not what i am looking for.

Could it be that this is not even possible?

I am guessing changes should take place around here:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        )
```

Comment: Go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246119/how-do-i-change-my-button-image-with-navigation-drawer-opening-and-closing?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246119/how-do-i-change-my-button-image-with-navigation-drawer-opening-and-closing?rq=1)

Comment: this isn't exactly what i am looking for as i am trying to change the navigation drawer icons specifically, not some other views. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based upon my reading of [the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java), you would need to fork the implementation of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and modify it to:

- Either hold two `Drawable` resource IDs or use a `LevelListDrawable` or something to represent the two states, and
- Modify `setActionBarUpIndicator()` to take the change listed above into account

Note that users are only now starting to come to grips with the "mini hamburger" indicator meaning that there is a navigation drawer. Switching away from that convention may harm, not improve, your app's usability.

Comment: Thanks's CW, you always seem to come up with the best answers around here.